# UK CRM software for charities similar to neonCRM

Tags: crm

[NeonCRM](https://www.neoncrm.com/) looks like it has everything we need,  reporting, charity event planning, donation tracking etc. Unfortunately the charity we are working with is based in the UK, and needs UK based support, as well as the options to display currency in pounds.

Has anyone got a recommendation for similar software but targeted towards the UK charities?

Comment: Have you contacted the NeonCRM people? Take a look at CRM Matrix

Comment: I've talked to neonCRM, no way to cater for UK customers unfortunately. I will look at CRM matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

[CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/) is well known for not-for-profit and civic sectors. It is open source, and integrates with CMS like drupal, wordpress, etc. So you can run your own installation or run the service provided. Features include: contact management, events, memberships, contributions/donations, reports, email marketing etc.

[SuiteCRM](https://suitecrm.com/) is a fork/successor/improvement on the old community version of SugarCRM.

Comment: Hi. Out of interest, please which of the two did you opt for?